# Introduction video with sound in Opencart

Tags: html, video, opencart

Is there a way to play video with sound right after loading Opencart website? I placed my video into the slider section and all seems to work fine, but the video is being played without sound.
My website: https://www.dd-outfit.com

Answer (score 0):

Your `video` tag has `muted=""` attribute. Here

```
<video autoplay="" playsinline="" muted="" class="lazyload ms-slide-bgvideo lazyloaded" style="opacity: 1; width: 848px; height: 477px; margin-top: -39.5px; margin-left: 0px;" src="image/catalog/journal3/videos/DD Outfit 6.mp4" data-ll-status="loaded"></video>
```

Remove `muted=""` from video module `.twig` file and the sound will play as long as video starts.

The .twig file shoult be located somewhere in **Master Slider** folder in journal3, or in Journal3 config.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.

In the path:
**dd-outfit.com/public_html/catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/module**

I found **master_slider.twig** file containing two matching lines:

 <video autoplay playsinline muted data-src="{{ item.videoSrc }}" class="lazyload"></video>

AND

 <video autoplay playsinline muted controls data-src="{{ subitem.videoSrc }}"></video>

I managed to remove the "muted" tag, but nothing changed and somehow the tag "muted" remains visible in inspector.

I can't find any file containing the exact line you specified in the answer.
Any ideas?

Comment: You have to cleat twig, ocmod and Journal cache. Try pls